# How to show data from 2 MongoDB documents on one page, using Mongoose, Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I’m using NodeJS, Express, EJS and Mongoose. I'm a little new to Mongoose, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

I have two Models defined and one document is linked to the other via ObjectId.

They look something like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const timerSchema = new Schema({
    customer: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Customer',
      required: true
    },
    detailed: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    summary: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
 
 }, { timestamps: true }

);


const custDataSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },

    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }, 

 }, { timestamps: true }
);
const Customer = mongoose.model('Customer', custDataSchema);
const Timer = mongoose.model('Timer', timerSchema);

module.exports = Timer;
module.exports = Customer;
```

I have all data entered via webpage, and it is updated to the database correctly.

I am able to get some the information from the Customer schema to populate with the following route:

```
router.get('/customers/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    Customer.findById(id)
    .then(result => {
        res.render('details', { customer: result, title: 'Customer Details' });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

})
```

However, I’m unable to figure out how to get the data from the Timer Model to show up on the same page.
Here is the html/ejs:

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="">
        <h2><%= customer.firstName %></h2>
      </div>
      <div>Email: <%= customer.email %></div>
      <div>Company: <%= tester.summary %> </div>
  </div>
```

My goal is to use Vanilla JS as much as possible (absolutely no JQuery) I know I’m missing something right in front of my face. Any ideas to lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else out there that needs the answer, I was able to assign the data to variables and get the expected result:

```
router.get('/customers/:id', async(req, res) => {
  try{
    const id = req.params.id;
    const timeLU = await Timer.find({customer: id})
    const custLU = await Customer.findById(id)

    res.render('details', { customer: custLU, timer: timeLU, title: 'Customer Details' });

  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
    }
 })
```